# Consulta en SQL que traiga registros con fecha mayor a 5 días a la fecha actual

Tags: sql-server

estoy tratando de hacer un query que traiga registros con fecha mayor a 5 días a la fecha actual, esto en SQL Server. A continuación el siguiente query que he logrado "armar" para poder probar:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[REGISTRAR_GASTOS]
WHERE [fecha_gasto] >= ADDDATE([fecha_gasto], interval 5  DAY) 
ORDER BY date_add DESC;
```

NOTA: Se que está mal, mi problema es que a nivel de sintaxis no sé como indicarle que me traiga datos de los siguientes 5 días.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: estas buscando la funcion getdate() en lugar de sumarle 5 a fecha gasto?

Comment: En realidad ese fue de prueba, pero no sé como "armar" el query con la sintaxis correcta para que me muestre resultados de los siguientes 5 días.

Comment: prueba con la funcion que te dije y me dices, el query esta bien

Comment: y lee los enlaces que te pase en el primer comentario

Answer (score 2):

Que tal te agrego un ejemplo para que cheques la forma en que trabaja el dateadd, el primer parametro es lo que le vas agregar en este caso es día, el segundo es cuantos dias, y el ultimo la fecha a la que le quieres agregar, en este caso es el día actual, si puedes visualizar en este caso se declaran como dates, si lo declaras como datetime te tomara en cuenta las horas, ya dependera de la manera en que lo quieras realizar, declaro 3 fechas y una tabla la primera es la fecha referencia a la que se le va hacer el incremento de días, la segunda es la fecha incrementada y la tercera es para hacer un ciclo para llenar una tabla y cheques el ejemplo, al final solo le pones que sea mayor a la fecha2 que es la fecha mas 5 días, saludos!

```
declare @fecha1 date = getdate(),
@fecha2 date = dateadd(day, 5, getdate()),
@fechaFin date = '20181231';

declare @tbFechas table(fecha date);

select @fecha1 fecha1, @fecha2 fecha2, @fechaFin fechaFin;   

begin tran
while(@fecha1<@fechaFin)
begin       
    insert @tbFechas(fecha) values(@fecha1);
    set @fecha1 = dateadd(day, 1, @fecha1);
end
rollback tran

select *
from @tbFechas
where fecha > @fecha2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones que necesitas para estos son: `DATEADD(datepart , number , date) o DATEDIFF(datepart , number , date) ,  GETDATE() O CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  y posiblemente `CAST O CONVERT`.

Tomando en cuenta lo hora en que se ejecuta la consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[REGISTRAR_GASTOS] 
WHERE [fecha_gasto] >= DATEADD(DAY, -5,GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY date_add DESC;
```

Si quieres que tome desde el inicio del dia:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[REGISTRAR_GASTOS] 
WHERE [fecha_gasto] >=CAST( DATEADD(DAY, -5,GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
ORDER BY date_add DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

La clausula where que puedes utilizar es

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, [fecha_gasto] , GETDATE()) > = 5
```

Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[REGISTRAR_GASTOS]
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, [fecha_gasto] , GETDATE()) > = 5
ORDER BY date_add DESC;
```